# Phone Number formatting: Excel to DB

Tags: python, excel, number-formatting, data-cleaning

I have a database with all variations to enter a phone number. It also includes special characters and  different formats entered by the user. The data is in Excel and I am trying to get all the phone numbers into a single format i.e, Countrycode - phone number Eg: +1 - 1234567899. I have phone numbers from different countries in the data. Can you guys please suggest on how to do this in Python?

Comment: How is this a django question actually ?

Comment: A python script can be written.  You can call the script django view you wrote. This packet is a nice field for the data base. 
 -> https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field

But this problem is not related to django

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Not a django issue. Format your excel file into a comma separated values (csv) file. From there, parsing should be straight forward.

Comment: Removed Django. The question has nothing to do with Django.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really specific to Django, however you will need to essentially parse the data. You can use string formatting, such as this:

```
str = 499-999-2342
str.replace("-", "")
print(str)
// 4999992342
```

It's fairly straightforward. You can do this with other characters as well. There's plenty of documentation on Python string formatting.